# Freeing memory in mex code

Tags: c, matlab, memory, malloc, mex

I am writing a mex code and I am thinking that I am not using memory very efficiently. Here is what I do. I am allocating memory for variable called out like

```
out=mxMalloc(sizeof(double)*N);

plhs[0]=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,N,mxREAL);

set(plhs[0],out);
```

The problem is that I am not freeing memory that I allocate for variable out because if I do I will receive segmentation error since I will use it in Matlab. So can anyone suggest me a better technique to do what above commands are doing ? Is there anyway to free memory for out or to avoid defining matrix of length 1X N?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to allocate the array with `mxMalloc`. `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` *already* allocates the array. Once you have your pointer to this data (obtained using `mxGetPr`), you can then fill the array with the necessary values.

```
double *out;

// Allocate memory for the first output
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,N,mxREAL);

// Get the pointer to the output data
out = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

// Run your algorithm here to populate out with the data you need
```

If for some reason you *do* need to create `out` in some other way, you want to copy the contents of that separate array into the output prior to freeing the memory.

```
double *out;
double *realout;

// Allocate data to use internally
out = mxMalloc(sizeof(double) * N);

// Initialize the array that will be returned to MATLAB 
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, N, mxREAL);
realout = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

// Now copy all values to the MATLAB output
for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    realout[j] = out[j];

// Now you can free up memory for out
mxFree(out)
```

Comment: Remember we want to assign out to the plhs[0] what you wrote seems to me that we have plhs[0[ and output is pointing to it. out in my case is vector of data 1XN and I am trying to assign it to plhs[0] that is my matlab output. Can you elaborate about your answer and also can you tell me if your output and my out are the same?

Comment: @justin Sorry, I meant `out`. You can allocate `out` at the beginning  (using `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` and then fill it within the rest of your mex file. There is no need to allocate it separately.